# How to select a node that is inside a sibling of a parent node using xpath expression?

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to select a node based on the known text inside a sibling of a parent node. To be clearer my HTML has the following structure:

```html
<k>
 <l>Known</l>
</k>
<k>
 <l>Desired</l>
</k>
```

My attempt:

```
//k//following-sibling::*[text()="Known"]
```

Returns:

> Known

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because basically you're selecting any descendant of `k` with the text `Known`.

(You're actually matching the `l` because it's a sibling of the whitespace before it. If you remove the whitespace (including line breaks), your xpath probably won't return anything.)

Try selecting the first following sibling `k`...

```
//k[l='Known']/following-sibling::k[1]/l
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe I was missing few things here: k[l='Know'] returns exactly the parent and also the fact that I was looking for the k[1]. I would point out that I used a node type test text() to get the string that I was looking for.